# IPython.display: SVG cannot render a svg image generated by svg_filter_line (official example)

Tags: python, matplotlib, svg, jupyter-notebook

I am running [svg_filter_line](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/misc/svg_filter_line.html#sphx-glr-gallery-misc-svg-filter-line-py) (official example) in Jupyter on MacOS with Python3.

SVG works well with lots of svg image (Worldmap image from wiki, for instance)

[image]

the original coding of svg_filter_line works well too.

[image]

running svg_filter_line generates a svg image named 'svg_filter_line.svg'.

SVG cannot render this svg image 'svg_filter_line.svg', no error, no warning.

[image]

Comment: there is only one svg_filter_line.svg file. what does 'common things' mean?

Comment: Interesting. I initially thought that the browser wouldn't be able to render the svg, but if you open the created file in Firefox, it renders as expected. So there is some interplay between the jupyter notebook and the SVG that prevents it from being included in the DOM-tree of the notebook page.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Chrome can render the created file 'svg_filter_line.svg' and other svg well. it seems that jupyter cell is the only place where the created file cannot be rendered well.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I was saying above.

Answer (score 4):

It was slightly hard to get to this. Here is the solution: While working with the files: I found that the type of file displayed by `display()` or `display_svg()` function is slightly different from each other (Difference is mainly in the namespace). As a workaround, had to re-save the SVG file using svgutils, follow by reading and displaying as below:

```
import svgutils.transform as sg
from IPython.display import SVG,display

#create new SVG figure
fig = sg.SVGFigure("16cm", "10cm")

# load matpotlib-generated figures
fig1 = sg.fromfile('svg_filter_line.svg')
plot1 = fig1.getroot()
fig.append([plot1])
fig.save("svg_filter_line2.svg")
display(SVG(filename='svg_filter_line2.svg'))
```

`svgutils` can  be installed as below:

`conda install -c conda-forge svgutils`

Comment: Cool, that's a nice solution. Do you have any idea about the origin of the problem? Would it be possible to change the original example to work out of the box, or what is it that svgutils does to the file that makes it work?

Comment: What I figured out is, `SVG(), display() or display_svg()` from `IPython.display` were able to read the svg file, but were not able to display. However, they succeeded in displaying svg's available over the internet. Further analysis showed that there was namespace difference, for the SVG's produced in the original implementation.


However, `svgutils` here need not be a true solution (depends on how you define a true solution as). But, what exactly is done in the work-around is creating a new SVG and then appending the contents of the previously created SVG.

Comment: (Extended comment) This way, we are able to incorporate the exising XML in the the namespace that IPython can use to interpret and render. (This is weired kind of encapsulation or a wrap up)

Comment: I will award this the bounty, even though it doesn't explain the source of the issue.